# RGB Cable Assignments - help

Tags: soldering, video, rgb

I have a video cable D-Sub 9 pin. Someone know the connector pin assignments to do a RGB 3 bnc cable? Someone can help me?
Below, the image of description of the cable
[image: description of the d-sub 9 pin]

Comment: I believe the 3xBNC cable system encodes the sync information into the green signal. You will need more than just wires to do that.

Comment: If the equipment was designed for it, the sync may already be present in the G signal. Check with a scope.

Comment: I know how to take a 9 pin rgb to a 3xBNC, but the pinout you shared is throwing me off. I'm used to seeing RGB, grounds, and sync lines. What is all of the vbs/y, c.sync/wen stuff?

Comment: I'd guess that the (G) pins are the grounds for the respective (X) pins

Comment: @I.Wolfe , I don't understand right these things.
I have a sony ccd video cam with these output signals. (in the picture).
I need connect this sony video cam at a recorder. But, this recorder have only "RGB 3 bnc" input.
I would like to know how i can connect the CCD video cam into my recorder, with these video output signals.

Thanks,

Rafael

Comment: @Rafa Camargo Oh ok I might not know then. I used mine to go from a dvd player to projector, so it was easier, I had both pinouts and they matched up RGB signals. Can you share the part number of the camera? And the recorder if you can.

Comment: @I.Wolfe The Video Cam is: Sony DXC-390 and the recorder is a Roxio GameCapture HD pro.
The quick guide of the camera: https://pro.sony.com/bbsccms/assets/files/mkt/remotemonitoring/brochures/RM_dxc-390.pdf

The quick guide of the game capture:
http://img.roxio.com/guides/products/gamecapture/hdpro/rgchdpro_qsg_en.pdf

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do it, unless I'm overlooking something. The Roxio takes in a component signal, and it looks like the camera only has RGB outputs. RGB has the 3 color signals and a sync, while component has a brightness signal and 2 color signals (the third color is derived from the other signals). You would have to convert the signal from RGB to component, which would require more than just a cable.

Comment: @I.Wolfe Okk , now I get it.
So...Do you know any device to convert this to component?
Thank U

Comment: The only converter I could find was a VGA (15 pin) to component. Your 9 pin apparently powers the camera as well as carries video signal. This cable: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/106837-REG/Sony_CCMC9DS_US_CCMC_9DS_US_Interconnect_Cable.html can break it out into 4 BNC rgb connecters for the signal and a cable for power. You can then take something like this: http://www.l-com.com/audio-video-vga-breakout-ext-cable-hd15-male-4-bnc-female-15-ft to put signal on a VGA 15 pin. I am not sure if this will work though, and the parts seem expensive for trying. Continued on next comment...

Comment: VGA 15 pin to component converter: http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011407&p_id=8668&seq=1&format=2 That is the only converter I found taking VGA to component. Again I'm not sure about how the signals will carry over, I would get a second opinion on it. You might consider rephrasing your question with more information and offer what I suggested as a possible answer and see what people say.